# Setting up C++ includes

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, include, header-files, c++20

Let's say I have a project directory where it has an include folder that has headers files (.hpp) and a src folder (.cpp). I am using visual studio code. How can I instead of writing `#include "../include/Person.hpp"` write `#include "Person.hpp"`?
My project has a structure like this:

```
project-name
     |
     |--src -- Main.cpp & Person.cpp
     |
     |--include -- Person.hpp
```

My Person.cpp has the implementations of Person.hpp.
My main file looks like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "../include/Person.hpp"
int main() {
    Person p("Allison");
    std::cout << p.name << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37522462/visual-studio-code-includepath https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57458423/vscode-not-recognizing-includes-from-includepath https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52910102/vscode-c-task-json-include-path-and-libraries

Comment: It looks like you need to add the include paths twice: once in c_cpp_properties.json for intellisense and once in tasks.json for the compiler to build it.

Comment: g++ -l ./include ./src/main.cpp -o ./bin/main.o gives fatal error: "Person.hpp": No such file or directory

Comment: Should it have been `../Include` instead of `./Include` in the above comment? Also remember this path has to be relative to the `main.cpp` file I believe.

Comment: Tried that too... the same error

Comment: Guess there is no way but to write the full relative include path in the source file

Comment: I was able to do a toy example of this using `g++ -I ./include/ ./src/main.cpp ./src/Person.cpp -o ./bin/test_app` with your described folder structure with just `#include "Person.hpp"` in my source files, running `g++` from the enclosing directory that contains `bin`, `src`, and `include` as folders. No fatal error.

Comment: @NathanPierson That actually worked.Thanks